# $http.get returns http code 401

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, angularjs

I am trying to use angularJS to connect to an API I wrote, currently the root route of the API displays the information of the API:

```
{
    "Company": "Test Company",
    "Version": "0.1"
}
```

When using jquerys `$.ajax()` to access the data, I get the json as expected. However when I use $http.get() in angularJS the error returned in the console is:

```
OPTIONS http://testapi.dev/ 401 (Unauthorized) angular.min.js:100
OPTIONS http://testapi.dev/ Invalid HTTP status code 401 angular.min.js:100
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://testapi.dev/. Invalid HTTP status code 401
```

Here is my code for the index Controller that attempts to pull said data:

```
var index = angular.module('index', ['$strap.directives']);

index.factory('infoFactory', function ($http) {

    var info_url = 'http://testapi.dev/';
    var login_url = info_url + 'login';

    var info = {};

    return {
        info: info,

        getInfo: function () {
            return $http.get(info_url);
        }
    };
});

index.controller('indexCtrl', function indexCtrl ($scope, infoFactory) {

    infoFactory.getInfo().success(function (data) {
        if (data.Success) {
            $scope.info = data.Data;
            infoFactory.info = data.Data;
        } else {
            alert(data.Message);
        }
    });     
});
```

Comment: I think your server should implement CORS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-Side_Access_Control look the script throw Chrome deleloper Tools  it could be very useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this change

```
   getInfo: function ($http) {
        return $http.get(info_url);
    }
```

Inject $http to your getInfo function

Comment: This just causes it to throw the error `TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined`